# Give a div scrollbars if parent div size is smaller

Tags: html, css

I have child div with a fixed size, when the liquid parent div has less width then the child, I want to keep the child inside the parent and give the child scrollbars.
[jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/mhkwQ/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
          <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.child{

   width: 500px;
   height: 400px;

   background-color: green;

}

.parent{

   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   padding: 50px;
   width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to the parent container:

```
.parent{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   padding: 50px;
   width: auto;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FdVMR/1/)

Comment: cool, but how can I now reach for example the content of the child that is on the right hand side?

Comment: Use the scroll bar? I don't think I understand